# email send from ipad without setup account

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

i want(i mean client :)) to send an email from a particular account.

in my app there is an option of sending a mail. 
now i want to do as any one from any ipad sends email from using this app will sent by one particular account. 
How can i do so?

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/63880-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-methods.html)

By looking at the class reference for MFMailComposeViewController in the documentation, I'd say you can't do anything about it. It's not very flexible unfortunately, same as sending SMS, and there you can't MMS with it, just SMS.

You can't specify a default email address. If you could, I suspect one could view this as a security risk for spam/unsolicited mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can't using Apple's API, it will use the Mail app and whatever account is setup in there.  You'll have to grab full sendmail client code and incorporate it into your app.